# PHP mkdir(); not working

Tags: php, directory, mkdir

I've been trying the function Mkdir that will be usefull in the project i'm working on. I've tried the simplest code possible but I can't get it to create the folder I want.

I've tried to changes my folder permissions, but that doesn't change (Nor 755 or 777) and the code keeps returning a fail.

Please have a look at my code :

```
<?php 
if(!mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/2017', 0777, true))
    {
        echo("echec");
    }
chmod($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/2017', 0777);
?>
```

The parent folder is "admin" and it permissions are set to 755.

Do you have any clue why this isn't working ?

EDIT : I remade it and it worked, no clue what the problem was.

Comment: try with `mkdir('2017'` or absolute path of the folder

Comment: `mkdir('/2017')` creates folder in a root directory of a file system (where `/etc` `/usr` and other stuff). Obviously your user don't have enough privileges for this.

Comment: your webserver may not be running in the right permission group for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Scuzzy Is there any way to change that ?

Comment: You could try using [system()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)  function to make the directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code

```
mkdir('/2017', 0777, true)
```

creates folder `2017` is a root folder of a file system.

Always set ethier full path to your folder, e.g.:

```
mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/2017', 0777, true);
// or
mkdir('/var/www/mysite/2017', 0777, true);
```

Or use `.` or `..` to define proper location:

```
// folder will be created in a same directory 
// as a script which executes this code
mkdir('./2017', 0777, true);

// folder will be created in a directory up one level
// than a script which executes this code
mkdir('../2017', 0777, true);
```

So, in your case it is obviously:

```
mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/admin/2017', 0777, true);
```

Comment: Edit you question with a new code, echo the path which you pass to `mkdir`.

Comment: Just for the book. Make sure the second parameter is `0777` and not `'0777'`. Has to be integer not string.

Answer (score 0):

### Example **#1 [mkdir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)** example

```
<?php
mkdir("/path/to/my/dir", 0700);
?>
```

Comment: And what? `/2017` is not a `path-to-dir`?